# Find partial derivatives, given directional derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

You are given that the directional derivatives of a function $f$, at the point $(a, b)$, in the direction of the two vectors $(1, 2)$ and $(−1, 1)$, are $2$ and $3$ respectively. Find the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(a, b)$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Do you know any formulas, Jack, that relate directional derivatives and partial derivatives?

Comment: http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY525/tln6.pdf

Answer (score 3):

We know that in general $\Bbb d f (a,b) (u,v) = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (a,b) u + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (a,b) v$. Replacing $(u,v)$ by $(1,2)$ and $(-1,1)$ gives us

$$\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (a,b) + 2 \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (a,b) = 2 \\
- \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (a,b) + \frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (a,b) = 3 ,$$

which is a $2 \times 2$ linear system in the unknowns $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (a,b)$ and $\frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (a,b)$. Solving it gives us $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x} (a,b) = - \frac 4 3$ and $\frac {\partial f} {\partial y} (a,b) = \frac 5 3$.

Comment: You have deprived OP of the joy of figuring out even a little bit of this for himself.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You might be right. Hopefully, he will find several other exercises where the above one came from that he will be able to solve by himself following the above model.